# SQL retrieval from tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table something like

```
EMPLOYEE_ID DTL_ID COLUMN_A COLUMN_B
---------------------------
JOHN        0       1           1
JOHN        1       3           1
LINN        0       1           12
SMITH       0       9           1
SMITH       1       11          12
```

It means for each person there will be one or more records with different `DTL_ID`'s value (0, 1, 2 .. etc).

Now I'd like to create a T-SQL statement to retrieve the records with `EMPLOYEE_ID` and `DTL_ID`.

If the specified `DTL_ID` is NOT found, the record with `DTL_ID=0` will be returned.

I know that I can achieve this in various ways such as checking if a row exists via `EXISTS` or `COUNT(*)` first and then retrieve the row.

However, I'd like to know other possible ways because this retrieval statement is very common in my application and my table have hundred thousand of rows.

In the above approach, I've had to retrieve twice even if the record with the `DTL_ID` specified exists, and I want to avoid this.

Comment: "If the specified DTL_ID is NOT found" - found where?

Comment: from the table ,of course. For eg, Select * from <Newly created View,Function here> where EMPLOYEE_ID='LINN' AND DTL_ID='1' . This statement returns the record whose DTL_ID=0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM table
   WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = ?? AND DTL_ID = ??
UNION
  SELECT *
    FROM table
   WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = ?? AND DTL_ID = 0
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                       FROM table
                      WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = ?? AND DTL_ID = ??)
```

You will of course have to fill in the ?? with the proper number.

Answer (score 2):

If DTL_ID is always 0 or positive:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table
where EmployeeID = @EmployeeID and DTL_ID in (@DTL_ID,0)
order by DTL_ID desc
```

If you're working across multiple employees in a single query, etc, then you might want to use ROW_NUMBER() if your version of SQL supports it.

Comment: Thanks. I think ,this one is better.

Comment: sorry Damien, but this will not work in case there are more than 2 DTL_ID values (0,1,2).

Comment: Damien is correct. It's exactly what I want. I'm expecting to get DTL_ID=0 by default if there're NOT record with DTL_ID specified. I'm NOT expecting to get a row with another LANG_ID(non-empty) if specified ID is NOT found.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Damien Never mind, I misunderstood the question. I assumed OP wanted all rows that wasn't 0. Good solution. In my solution you can see how I had read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ISNULL(DTL_ID, 0)` in your final `SELECT` query

Comment: He wants the row with DTL_ID = 0. And ISNULL will not work if the query returns no rows.

Comment: It depends on query he will use, I believe here is should be LEFT/RIGHT JOIN on some another table

Comment: What I want is the whole row, NOT the single DTL_ID column.

Comment: @Kai: so if you join another table on DTL_ID, replace DTL_ID in SELECT statement by ISNULL(DTL_ID, 0) - it will replaces all NULLs by 0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E1.EMPLOYEE_ID, ISNULL(E2.DTL_ID, 0), E1.COLUMN_A, E1.COLUMN_B EMPLIYEES AS E1
LEFT JOIN EMPLIYEES AS E2
ON E1.EMPLOYEE_ID = E2.EMPLOYEE_ID AND E2.DTL_ID = 42
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(DTL_ID) ...
WHERE DTL_ID IN (@DTL_ID, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `top` and `union`, e.g.:

```
declare @t table(id int, value int, c char)
insert @t values (1,0,'a'), (1,1,'b'), (1,2,'c')

declare @id int = 1;
declare @value int = 2;

select top(1) *
from
(
    select *
    from @t t
    where t.value =  @value and t.id = @id

    union all

    select *
    from @t t
    where t.value = 0

)a
order by a.value desc
```

If `@value = 2` than query returns `1 2 c`. If `@value = 3` than query returns `1 0 a`.